# Equivalent to applets, that work with Chrome browser

Tags: java, html, .net, google-chrome, applet

After doing some research  i found that chrome remove the support for NPAPI which is the plugin that let use applets in the browsers.

Now my question is there something equivalent to an applet that all the browsers can use(Firefox,Chrome,IE,Safari)? I'm looking for general ideas and i can start doing some research on the suggestions you offer. What i want to do with the applet is doing a HttpRequest POST method from a the applet to a remote server.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to move to [Java Web Start](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).  Basically this allows a Java application to be run (and optionally installed) from the browser (but, importantly, not *in* the browser).  It is pretty easy to convert your applet to a JWS application.

Again, this is not a one-to-one replacement for applets but many applets can be used this way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will try it out and see how it works.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript with jQuery perhaps...